# Modelagem de banco de dados Sql Server

Tags: c#, sql, banco-de-dados

Bom dia amigos,

Tenho um projeto que tem basicamente dois tipos de produtos, os produtos simples, como itens de mercado, arroz kg, feijão 1 kg , etc.. e itens compostos como cestas básicas , formadas por itens simples , ou seja dentro da cesta básica temos arroz, feijão .. etc, eu tenho uma tabela que guarda o cadastro dos produtos simples, tenho uma outra tabela que guarda os produtos compostos e os produtos simples que estão associados a ele,e tenho também uma tabela que salva o histórico de saídas dos produtos,mais no caso de um produto composto ela salva apenas o código do mesmo e a quantidade que saiu, como posso fazer para no ato da saída de um produto composto os itens simples que o formam sejam debitados também , como posso modelar meu banco para tal ?

Comment: De infinitas maneiras. O problema é que você está confundindo itens de consumo interno com ítens vendidos. Em princípio, quando você compra um saco de feijão para vender como saco de feijáo, está revendendo apenas. Quando você está pondo um saco de feijão na cesta básica, você está "consumindo" esse saco de feijão, para "fabricar" uma cesta básica. Uma cesta básica não é um produto composto. É um ítem único também, que "gasta" ítens do estoque ao ser feito. Consolide os conceitos antes da modelagem. Claro que nada te obriga a fazer da forma que eu disse, mas convém que corresponda à realidade.

Comment: Pense na sua cesta como um carro. Pra fazer o carro, você gasta parafusos, pneus, metros de fio, tecidos, interruptores. Quem compra compra um carro, e não um punhado de peças. Quem compra as peças é a fábrica, e ela "gasta" todas ao fazer o carro. Eventualmente você compra peças separadas da fábrica, para reposição, e elas podem vir do mesmo estoque que veio a do carro. O que mudou foi o destino da peça (consumo, no primeiro caso, venda, no segundo caso)

Comment: Aplicando ao seu caso, um exemplo bem simplificado seria: estoque atual: 30 sacos de feijão, 12 cestas básicas. Fabricou 2 cestas (cada uma com 2 sacos de feijão) consumiu 4 itens do estoque, Vendeu 3 sacos avulsos, sairam mais 3 unidades do estoque. Estoque atual: 23 sacos de feijão, 14 cestas básicas.